# Google maps adding a new marker every update

Tags: android, google-maps

been trying for a while to sort my maps problem, which is the marker. every time the map updates it adds a new marker. this leaves several markers on the same location.

I want to get this sorted before adding other content like directions.

```
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        return;// 
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); // shows location on map
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    listener = new LocationUpdateListener();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
}
private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions() // This adds in a marker
            .position(latLng)
            .title("Reverse Geo Toast here ???"); // when marker clicked, it will display you are here
    mMap.addMarker(options);
   // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    float zoomLevel = (float) 10; //This zooms into the marker
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoomLevel));
}
```

Comment: So you want to update the position of your existing marker instead of adding a new one?

Answer (score 1):

You can update the position of an existing marker using `setPosition` ([Reference](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#public-methods)):

```
private Marker marker;

// ...

private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

    if (marker == null) {
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions() // This adds in a marker
                .position(latLng)
                .title("Reverse Geo Toast here ???"); // when marker clicked, it will display you are here
        marker = mMap.addMarker(options);
    }
    else {
        marker.setPosition(latLng);
    }
    // mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    float zoomLevel = (float) 10; //This zooms into the marker
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoomLevel));
}
```